# How can I create google sign in and use google account for showing content?

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, android-calendar

I am creating calendar in android and I want to add google sign in. I want to show events added in calendar in bases of google account. Can anyone guide me which tools to use and how it can be done?

Comment: This might help oauth https://youtu.be/KwOmVpd1DUA

Comment: I think video shows webapp and I want to create android app.

Comment: I think you might be interested in this article, [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) or this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth), if you understand Kotlin.